# check the checkbox on load but if the page reloads must remember last state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, persistence, reload

I have a group of checkbox that must be checked on load of the page. I have a onload script for auto checking the checkbox but when I unchecked the checkbox and reloads the page, it's still checked. How can it remember it's last state? Thanks in advance

Comment: use a cookie/local storage to store the state

Comment: I need html and css classes to solve  your problem. so can you create JS Fiddle for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   var i, checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

  function save() {
      for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].value, checkboxes[i].checked); 
    }
}

 function load_() {
     for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].value) === 'true' ?      
   true:false;
  }
 }
```

working fiddler:- http://jsfiddle.net/sQuEy/104/